# Using multiple instances of datetimepicker working with a Range between date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm trying to get the "Range between date" work for multiple instances. Each instance couple has a different id. The datetimepicker is added using the class, which is the same for all instances:

```
var format = "d-m-Y H:i";
var startSelector = ".date_timepicker_start";
var endSelector = ".date_timepicker_end";
```

Now I want to get the id of the field that is clicked, then replace start by end, so I have the id of the matching end field, and the use this result to get the value:

```
$(startSelector).datetimepicker( {
  format : format,
  onShow : function(ct) {
    var selectedid = $(this).attr('id');
    var selid = selectedid.replace("start", "end");
    var val = $("#"+selid).val();
    console.log('id: '+selectedid);
    var opts = {
      formatDate : "d-m-Y",
      maxDate : val ? val.split(' ')[0] : false
    };
    this.setOptions(opts);
  },
```

});

The var selectedid = $(this).attr('id');returns undefined however.
I also tried with this.id etc..
Someone got an idea? I'm probably overlooking something..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` inside the onShow method refers to the datetimepicker div and not the input. Thus you see `undefined`

But the onShow method has other parameters

> onShow : function(date, $input, event)

You can make use the for the second parameter and get the id by `$input.attr('id')`

Also, you don't need such multiple selectors. You can do something like this

```
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker" id="start" />
<input type="text" class="datetimepicker" id="end"/>
```

Now you can use just one selector like this

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  onShow: function(date, $input, event){
    alert($input.attr('id'));
  }
});
```

```js
var format = "d-m-Y H:i";
// var startSelector = ".date_timepicker_start";
// var endSelector = ".date_timepicker_end";
var options = {
  format: format,
  onShow: function(date, $input, event) {
    alert($input.attr('id'));
  }
};
/* Date Picker Validation JS */
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker(options);
```

```css
.xdsoft_datetimepicker {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.506);
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker iframe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 75px;
  height: 210px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
/*For IE8 or lower*/

.xdsoft_datetimepicker button {
  border: none !important;
}
.xdsoft_noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.xdsoft_noselect::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
.xdsoft_noselect::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_inline {
  display: inline-block;
  position: static;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_datepicker,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker {
  display: none;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_datepicker.active,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker.active {
  display: block;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_datepicker {
  width: 224px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_showweeks .xdsoft_datepicker {
  width: 256px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker {
  width: 58px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_datepicker.active+.xdsoft_timepicker {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 3px
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_mounthpicker {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label i,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_prev,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_next,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_today_button {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label i {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-position: -92px -19px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_prev {
  float: left;
  background-position: -20px 0;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_today_button {
  float: left;
  background-position: -70px 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_next {
  float: right;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_next,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_prev,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_today_button {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 0 none currentColor;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  outline: medium none currentColor;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 20px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_prev,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_next {
  float: none;
  background-position: -40px -15px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 14px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_prev {
  background-position: -40px 0;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box {
  height: 151px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div > div:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_today_button:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_next:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 182px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label:hover>span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label:hover i {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 101;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  max-height: 160px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select.xdsoft_monthselect {
  right: -7px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select.xdsoft_yearselect {
  right: 2px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #ff8000;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option {
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 5px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option.xdsoft_current {
  background: #33AAFF;
  box-shadow: #178FE5 0 1px 3px 0 inset;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_month {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar {
  clear: both;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_year {
  width: 48px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td > div {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar th {
  height: 25px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar th {
  width: 14.2857142%;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_showweeks .xdsoft_calendar td,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_showweeks .xdsoft_calendar th {
  width: 12.5%;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar th {
  background: #F1F1F1;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_today {
  color: #33AAFF;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_default,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_current,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div.xdsoft_current {
  background: #33AAFF;
  box-shadow: #178FE5 0 1px 3px 0 inset;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_other_month,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_disabled,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div.xdsoft_disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_other_month.xdsoft_disabled {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background: #ff8000 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_disabled:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div.xdsoft_disabled:hover {
  color: inherit !important;
  background: inherit !important;
  box-shadow: inherit !important;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar th {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  color: #999;
  cursor: default;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_copyright {
  color: #ccc !important;
  font-size: 10px;
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_copyright a {
  color: #eee !important;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_copyright a:hover {
  color: #aaa !important;
}
.xdsoft_time_box {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.xdsoft_scrollbar >.xdsoft_scroller {
  background: #ccc !important;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.xdsoft_scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 7px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.xdsoft_scroller_box {
  position: relative;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.506);
  background: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444444;
  border-left: 1px solid #333333;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-top: 1px solid #333333;
  color: #cccccc;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div {
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border-top: 1px solid #222222;
  color: #999999;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label {
  background-color: #000;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #000;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option:hover {
  color: #000;
  background: #007fff;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option.xdsoft_current {
  background: #cc5500;
  box-shadow: #b03e00 0 1px 3px 0 inset;
  color: #000;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label i,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_prev,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_next,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_today_button {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar th {
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 1px solid #222222;
  color: #999999;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar th {
  background: #0e0e0e;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_today {
  color: #cc5500;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_default,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_current,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div.xdsoft_current {
  background: #cc5500;
  box-shadow: #b03e00 0 1px 3px 0 inset;
  color: #000;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div:hover {
  color: #000 !important;
  background: #007fff !important;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar th {
  color: #666;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_copyright {
  color: #333 !important;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_copyright a {
  color: #111 !important;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_copyright a:hover {
  color: #555 !important;
}
.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_time_box {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_scrollbar >.xdsoft_scroller {
  background: #333 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<div class="input-daterange input-group">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control datetimepicker" id="start" autocomplete="off" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control datetimepicker" id="end" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

Comment: This works! I saw some people using $input, but was not sure how to use it in this case, pretty easy!
To make it use only one selecter would need some extra code to use the minDate and maxDate at the right time..

Answer (score 0):

Instead try to iterate over the items first using the jQuery `each()` function and prepare the options before you create the instance of the datetimepicker:

```
$(startSelector).each(function(){
    var $this=$(this); //local reference of jQuery object

    var selectedid = $this.attr('id');
    var selid = selectedid.replace("start", "end");
    var val = $("#"+selid).val();
    console.log('id: '+selectedid);

    $this.datetimepicker( {
        format : format,
        formatDate : "d-m-Y",
        maxDate : val ? val.split(' ')[0] : false
    });
});
```